# android: Log in Button

Tags: android, passwords, android-toast

I'm having problem with my Log in activity.. the button will load the next activity even though no data inputted on the text field..
here's the code...

```
public void onButtonClick(View v){
        if(v.getId()== R.id.Blogin) {
            EditText a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFusername);
            String str = a.getText().toString();

            EditText b = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFpassword);
            String pass = b.getText().toString();


           String password = helper.searchPass(str);

            if(pass.equals(password))
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(User.this, Userlog.class);
                i.putExtra("Username",str);
                startActivity(i);
            }

            else
            {
                Toast temp = Toast.makeText(User.this, "Username and Password don't match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                temp.show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for empty strings

replace

```
if(pass.equals(password))
```

with

```
if(pass.equals(password) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(str) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass))
```

This should work.

Cheers

Comment: Can you mark this as answer if it serves the purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a `String` is empty using the **TextUtils** class's `isEmpty` method, which is a **static** one.

```
// Checks if a username & a password were typed, then checks if password is correct
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(str) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass) && pass.equals(password))
```

**Notice** that you are not checking whether the `username` is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

In you `helper. searchPass()`, do you return an empty string if no usrName is matched?If so, you have to check if the returned string is empty or you can return another special value :D